# Newbie - Manipulating closures and For Loops

Tags: javascript, html, css

The answer to why this code is not working is because: The problem with this method is is you're not providing a function as the second argument. You're calling a function - that function is making things blue. It's not returning a function that is making things blue. So you're making things blue immediately and, when the click happens, there's nothing to call, because the function you called returned nothing.

**But I'm lost after the first sentence. could someone dumb this down? perhaps a visual explanation of the code would help!**

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/2yfj89af/1/

```
var submitSOBox = document.getElementsByClassName("submitSOBox");

for (i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor(i));
}

function SOBoxColor(i) {
    submitSOBox[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Did you get the reason it isn't working from another question you asked?

Comment: It's the difference between referncing a function and calling a function, that you don't get. You call the function, it returns a result, and that is **no function**; but addEventListener needs a function.

Comment: Your `i` is a global variable. **The usage of global variables are strictly deprecated.** Do not use. use `"use strict";` and declare all variables.

Comment: When you see the parentheses at the end `SOBoxColor(i)`, it means you are calling the function. In other-words you are telling the function to do it's work. When you give the function without parentheses `SOBoxColor`, you are actually giving the function itself. The second parameter in `addEventListener` takes a function, and it will call it when you trigger a click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason explained: you have this line:

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor(i));
```

This calls `addEventListener` which expects a function as the last argument. You provide `SOBoxColor(i)`, which is not a function, but a value returned by a function -- you call it. To pass a function, you would need to pass something like `SOBoxColor`, so without calling it. This is needed because your browser needs to know what to call when the click event happens.

Now, passing just `SOBoxColor` will not do what you want. Yes, it will make that `SOBoxColor` gets called when a click happens, but you will not have the `i` value passed to it.

To achieve that, you need a modified version of your function that somehow has the `i` value pre-filled as argument. Luckily there is a way to create such a modified function with the `bind` method, which returns the same function, but with some things bound to it:

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor.bind(submitSOBox[i], i));
```

The first argument of `bind` determines what the special [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) object will represent when `SOBoxColor` is called, and the second argument is what `i` will be.

Now, this will work.

But you can do it even nicer if you would use the `this` keyword in your `SOBoxColor` function, because then you don't even need the `i` parameter:

```
function SOBoxColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

... and your binding can also do without the `i` argument:

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor.bind(submitSOBox[i]));
```

It can still be done more concisely, because when the click happens, the browser will already provide a nice service to us: it sets the `this` keyword to the element to which you added the event handler, so in the end it is not even necessary to bind `submitSOBox[i]` to it explicitly. This will work also:

```
 submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor);
```

... provided you changed the `SOBoxColor` function to work with `this`.

Comment: This is the most clear,precise, and simple explanation in my opinion. Although I just want to note that [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Specifications) may not be supported in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the event listener like you are:

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor(i));
```

It is calling the function `SOBoxColor()`, expecting it to return a function that will be called when the event listener is triggered.

By return a function, I mean like this:

```
function SOBoxColor(){
  return function(){
    alert("hello")
    //Do stuff
  }
}
```

If you replaced the current function with the one above, it would alert "hello" whenever the click listener is triggered.

How would you fix this?

Simply put the functions name in it, without calling it:

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor);
```

The problem you are going to have now is, with your current function, `SOBoxColor`:

```
function SOBoxColor(i) {
    submitSOBox[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

You are sending the number as a parameter to select the appropriate element, which you can't do anymore.

However, this isn't a problem, since you were selecting the element incorrectly in the first place.
Instead of selecting it with it's index in the `HTMLCollection` `submitSOBox`, just reference the current element with the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword:

```
function SOBoxColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

So, your complete code should now look like:

```
var submitSOBox = document.getElementsByClassName("submitSOBox");

for (var i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor);
}

function SOBoxColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming calling a function must be done by

```
functionName();
```

But it's not the only way of calling functions. You could input a function as an argument, use the call method: `functionName.call(null,args)`, etc.

What `functionName();` does is make Javascript go, "Hey, I need to find out what that function returns." So if functionName is like

```
function functionName(){
    console.log("hello!");
    return undefined;
};
```

Javascript will try to simplify everything. It will run through your function, console log "hello!" while it's busy working, and in the very end figure out what your function returns:

```
undefined;
```

Think of it like simplifying math expressions back in algebra class or something.

In your case, you're telling the click event to call *whatever is returned by SOBoxColor(i).* So if SOBoxColor looked like this:

```
function SOBoxColor(i) {
    submitSOBox[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    return 9000;
}
```

Your click event would look like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', 9000);
}
```

addEventListener is a function that wants a function as the 2nd argument, not a number. so nothing would happen.

Comment: Thank you so much! just for future references what is the proper javascript term for calling functions like this: "functionName(i);"? I would like to know more about them :)

Answer (score 0):

As you are said the function returns nothing. in fact it is not a function at all. The idea of closure is to return **function** which uses values in outer scope.

```
var submitSOBox = document.getElementsByClassName("submitSOBox");

for (i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    //changes are possible here but we'll do it later
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor(i));
    //in your initial code SOBoxColor(i) returned undefined (no return)
    //and event listener must be a function. Yours was not.
}

//change your function like this:
function SOBoxColor(i) {
    //get the element from collection. 
    //both collection and i are available at this point
    var elem = submitSOBox[i];
    return function(){
       //function knows elem from parent scope
       elem.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    };
}
```

I hope this explanations are helpful.

### Extra

This is an exercise with **closure**. If it were not then it would be simpler solution:

```
var submitSOBox = document.getElementsByClassName("submitSOBox");

for (i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
           this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
           //in this context **this** is clicked element 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor(i));
```

He is excecuting the function SOBoxColor with the current value of i as argument.
Also when when you add an event listener to an element, you have already the implicit value of this pointing at the DOM element. So just the change the code:

```
function SOBoxColor() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
var submitSOBox = document.getElementsByClassName("submitSOBox");

for (i = 0; i < submitSOBox.length; i++) {
    submitSOBox[i].addEventListener('click', SOBoxColor);//your passing the function
}
```

Also it's all more simple very simple with jQuery:

```
$(".submitSOBox").click(function(){ $(this).css("background-color","blue"); });
```